# How to get data of matrix fields?

Tags: matrix

below is my controller code for getting a data of prodcuts.

```
$service = craft()->entries;
$entry = $service->getEntryById(108);

$title = $entry->getTitle();
$description = $entry->description;
$overview = $entry->productOverview;
$price = $entry->price;

$slider = $entry->productSlider;
```

i store a slider data into matrix fields.

Block type = productSlider

fields is = images,title

Thanks